# Getting Images From file and Adding them to Array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to create a program that checks if someone is going to Happy Hour. If not, it lists those who aren't and puts their picture next to their name.

I'm able to achieve all but get the images locally and store them in an array (which would be added to pictureArray(i)).

(You can see the commented out sections are where I've tried to get the images...)

Any ideas?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim ITLPList() As String = {"Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Name 4", "Name 5", "Name 6"}
'  Dim imageList As New ImageList
' Dim fileSteam As New System.IO.FileStream(sFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
' Dim img As Image
' Dim sFileName As String = "C:\Users\turcotd\Desktop\ITLPers\itlp1.jpg"

Dim itlpTally() As String
Dim labelArray(5) As Label
Dim pictureArray(5) As PictureBox

Dim intTally As Integer
Dim i As Integer = 0

Public itlpIndex As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    itlpName.Text = ITLPList(0)
    labelArray(0) = lblPerson0
    labelArray(1) = lblPerson1
    labelArray(2) = lblPerson2
    labelArray(3) = lblPerson3
    labelArray(4) = lblPerson4

    pictureArray(0) = picITLP0
    pictureArray(1) = picITLP1
    pictureArray(2) = picITLP2
    pictureArray(3) = picITLP3
    pictureArray(4) = picITLP4

End Sub

Private Sub btnYes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnYes.Click

    If (i < 6) Then
        itlpName.Text = ITLPList(i)
        i = i + 1

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnNo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNo.Click

    If (i < 6) Then
        'Names
        itlpName.Text = ITLPList(i)
        intTally = intTally + 1
        lblTally.Text = intTally
        labelArray(i).Text = ITLPList(i)

        'Images
        '    img = Image.FromStream(fileSteam)
        '   fileSteam.Close()
        '  imageList.Images.Add(img)
        '  pictureArray(i).Image = imageList.Images.Item(0)
        '  img.Dispose()

        ' img = Image.FromFile(sFileName)

        i = i + 1
    End If
    itlpName.Text = ITLPList(i)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all jpg's  in a directory as [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) in the following way:

```
Dim dir = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\turcotd\Desktop\ITLPers")
Dim images = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? It's not working for me. Can you please explain how I put each jpg from a folder into an Image array? thanks

Comment: @Growler: Then you should explain what's not working, do you get any errors? I've showed you the way how you can get all jpg's in a folder as List(Of FileInfo). A [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is a lot better than an Array, it's even [better than an ArrayList](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2008/10/why-should-i-use-list-and-not-arraylist.html). If you insist on Arrays, you could simply call `dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray` instead.

Comment: @Growler: Look at the [FileInfo-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for further informations. For example you need to call [FileInfo.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx) to get the image-name(filename without path) or [FileInfo.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) to get the Full-Path. If that doesn't help you should show what you've tried.

Comment: @Growler: I've added more informations on your following question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8877377/284240 Consider to accept this answer as well if that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the file into the PictureBox from a file is a very straightforward operation:

```
picITLP0.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\turcotd\Desktop\ITLPers\itlp1.jpg")
```