# Add several .jpg's from file to image array

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'll keep this short and simple... I asked this question before, but It wasn't answered.
I'd like to get several images from a folder, and add them to an array.
This is not working, can someone explicitly tell me how to do it? Thanks!

On Form load:

```
Private Sub Button1_Add(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim PictureArray As New List(Of Image)
    For Each item As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\turcotd\Desktop\ITLPers", "*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim _Image As Image = Image.FromFile(item)
        PictureArray.Add(_Image)
    Next

    If (i < 6) Then
        Dim pb As New PictureBox
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb)
        pb.Image = PictureArray(i)
        i = i + 1
```

[image]
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i've showed you how to get the images of a [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) not from a FileInfo like above!

I've used a strong typed `List(Of FileInfo)` in [my answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8842768/284240) instead of an Array because it's a lot better, [even than an ArrayList](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2008/10/why-should-i-use-list-and-not-arraylist.html). You can access the items in a List the same you would access the items in an Array(via Index or "foreach").

If you anyway insist on using an Array, you simply need to use the [ToArray-Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) instead of [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx). For example:

```
Dim imageArray = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray
```

Look at the [FileInfo-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for further informations. For example you need to call [FileInfo.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx) to get the image-name(filename without path) or [FileInfo.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) to get the Full-Path.

So this should work:

```
Dim dir = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\turcotd\Desktop\ITLPers")
Dim images = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList
Dim pictures As New List(Of PictureBox)
For Each img In images
    Dim picture As New PictureBox
    picture.Image = Image.FromFile(img.FullName)
    pictures.Add(picture)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. But now, how would I access a certain index in the list of PictureBoxes. What I mean is, let's say the name of the actual pictureBox is "picBox1"... then how could I say something like:

picBox1 = (pictures(1))
picBox2 = (pictures(2))

follow what I mean?

Comment: @Growler: As i've already said: you can access the items via index, for example:  `Dim picBox1 = pictures(1)`. But please note that a List is zero-based(just as an Array). So if you want to get the first item you need `pictures(0)`.

Comment: I tried this. lol. I feel like I'm coming off as an idiot, but I really have tried these things, not sure why nothing is working except for statically adding the images like so:  

Dim imageArray() As String = {"C:\Users\turcotd\Desktop\ITLPers\dan.jpg", "C:\Users\turcotd\Desktop\ITLPers\marcus.jpg"}

Comment: Please specify "not working". Do you get any exceptions? Have you debugged to see what happens?

Comment: It's compiling without exceptions. I went through the debugging, and stepped through.. each step made sense. The images are just not populating the pictureBoxes on run. Mind if I send you my project file?, it's quite small.

Comment: @Growler: Sorry, but i still don't understand what's not working or what should be the expected result. You don't need the part behind the `for each`, for example: `Dim picITLP0 = pictures(0)`. The "array" already exists as `List(Of PictureBox)`. What do you want to do with the PictureBoxes?

Comment: Each picture box in list will display a a unique image from the image list. I have a pic to show of end result but I cant post images yet.

Comment: @Growler: Please specify what you want to do with the pictures, it's obvious that you want to show them. But where and how? It works perfectly for me, so i don't see the problem. Loading PictureBoxes does not mean that they will be shown anywhere, but that was not part of any of your questions.

Comment: id like to display them on the form in picture boxes picbox1 thru picbox5. I'm not sure how else I can describe it. Can I email u a pic of the end result?

Comment: @Growler: You should show the pic of the endresult in your question. Why do you want to add 5 PictureBoxes statically? The code will add one PictureBox for every jpg-file found in the specified directory. So it's possible that there are (sometime) more or less than 5 pictures. You can use  a ListView to show all of your images: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.largeimagelist.aspx

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to display pictures :/ I was statically adding  them because I wanted them in certain positions on the form. Plus I wasn't aware of things like listview. I'll check your link out.

Comment: Have you tried the ListView, what is the best choice for a List of PictureBoxes imho. It has a property [Alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.alignment.aspx), set tit to left to let the images scroll horizontally.

Comment: I'm going with Flowlayoutpanel. Question: can I add an image to a picture box without using a For loop? I don't want to have all images appear at run time, rather 1 by 1 as the Add button is clicked.

Comment: Yes of course. If you want to load picturebox #6 in your Image-List you simply need: `yourPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(images(5).FullName)`

Comment: Solved! Tim, thank you for painstakingly going through the process with me. I've updated my code above with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

An image is not a datatype you can use [fileinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) to read the images into an byte array.

Tim's answer [here at your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842609/getting-images-from-file-and-adding-them-to-array) does that very well it just puts it into a list.
You can then call thelist.toarray and now your list is an array.

**EDIT:**
i found this link for you it will help.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/ImageProccessing.aspx

It is a pretty simple process.

The issue is your thinking of an image as an string or an integer and its not. It is a collection of bytes. Hope this helped.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried his way, and it is not working. So what goes in here assuming I've followed Tim's answer: pictureArray(i).Load(what goes here?)

Answer (score 0):

[image: btn26 code is what i am referring]
Dear friend Growler,
     I have enclosed a button_Click code which perfectly picks the right image
from the right path and loads to pdf.I also have some text transfered from
multiline textbox to a richtextbox which goes 1st to pdf followed by images.
Your code and the and the corrections given  are not working.I am using 
VS 2017 community as backup and use VB.Net 14 (windows 10 goes without 
saying).I have given 2 screenshots also.
      btn26 is the button.I have enlrged the code portion so that i need not write it
again.
Regards
kvinvisibleguy

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image with text in pdf]

```
This is the pdf image.I have just shown you one image with some text 
at the end of my xaml file.The 2nd image is just below the image shown.
Regards
```